# google map direction points

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I have a gmap with direction line displayed on it (2 or more points).  Is there any way to get all points from map depending viewport (zoom level), only those that user can see ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I won't give you the tea spoon version, but here is how you do it. First of all, make sure you have all your markers available in an array.

1. Get the bounds from your map: `map.getBounds()`. This will return a `LatLngBounds` object, which contains the coordinates of the bottom left point of your viewport as well as the top right part.
2. Iterate through all your markers. Get their positions: `marker.getPosition()` and check if they are **above** and to the **right of** the map bounds south west point, as well as **below** and to the **left of** the map bounds north east point.
3. If they are, add these points to an array.

That array now contains all the points in your viewport. Repeat as necessary.

More information can be found in the [Google Maps API v3 reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference)